# Is it possible to save Java method in some Collections such as list?

Tags: java

I know that some language such as python can do this:

```
maps = []
cur = 1
maps.append(function)
for func in self.maps:
    cur = func(cur)
```

It adds a function to list and can iteratively call it. I'm wondering if Java can do the similar thing, if yes, how can it be done?

Comment: Hint: use a `List<IntUnaryOperator>`.

Comment: The proper way to do that in Java is to go through functional interfaces and then use for example method references `List<Runnable> tasks = List.of(Foo::printHello);` (or lambdas or anonymous classes or regular classes that implement the interface)

Comment: I'm not sure why this question asking about Lists is closed as duplicates asking about Arrays. They are different entities, are they not? It seems to be the case since the answers on the targets say "no" but the answer here says "yes".

Comment: @TylerH I agree.  I reopened it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can store a lambda in a list.

```
List<Function<Double, Double>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(v->v*20);
list.add(v->v*30);

System.out.println(list.get(0).apply(10.));
System.out.println(list.get(1).apply(10.));
```

prints

```
200
300
```

Comment: This example might be better off using `DoubleUnaryOperator` (to avoid boxing/unboxing)

Comment: True.  Didn't think of it.  But since there are so many options, in terms of number of arguments, types, etc, I guess this will still drive home the point.